# How to specify multiple ECDHE named curve in HAProxy?

Tags: ssl, configuration, haproxy

I was browsing SSLab's server test page and found that CloudFront accepts multiple ECDHE named curve. Then I'm wondering can I do it on my HAProxy to maximize security and compatibility. It is possible in HAProxy? If yes, how can I do it?